# How to view full image (preview) in a Google Doc? (e.g., hover over)

Tags: google-docs, images

How can I view the full image of an image in a Google Doc?  (e.g., hover over image to get a popup with the whole full-sized image)

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please show wht you tried, add a brief description of your search efforts and tell us if you are looking for a built in featured, a Google Apps Script, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to still be no way to do this unfortunately. And to boot, there's also no way to just save the image or open it in a new tab.

What I've had to do is copy the image into a text editor like LibreOffice Writer, then save the image from there. Then I can open it with my default image viewer. Quite the workaround but at least it works.

Answer (score -2):

You will see the original image size within the cell if you display it at that size. Here is tips a pic in a cell, plus a 3/4 size view of it (preview)

The first instructs you to resize the picture inside the cell, maintaining its aspect ratio.
2. Extends or compresses the image so that it fits within the cell.
Leaving the image at original size results in cropping.
4 provides the ability to specify a customized size.
This mode prevents the cell from resizing to fit the image.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @BAZZHOOD :  "within the cell" -- what is a "cell"?  This question is about a Google Doc -- are you referring to a Google Sheet instead?

"Here is tips...(preview)" -- did you intend to post a screenshot?

"The first... 2... 4..."  -- what are these numbers referring to?

Comment: Seems like this was just copied from somewhere.